# zzzprojects/Entity Framework Plus global filters with dynamic variables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

I need to create a global filter for my db context. The filter should show only objects with the same companyId as the current user.

Right now, I am passing companyId like so:

```
  public MyDB(int companyId) : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {

            this.Filter<BaseModel>(q => q.Where(x =>  (x.CompanyId == companyId || x.IsGlobal==true) && x.IsDeleted == false));
    }
```

But, It doesn't work well with lazy loading(virtual properties). So, I need to implement a global filter and I have no idea where to start and how to pass the companyId variable into it.

Here is my ApplicationUser

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

}
```

CompanyId is equal to current's user CompanyId. Each user could belong to one company. So, companyId won't change while a user logged in.

Thank you for all your help

Comment: To answer this question, we need first to know if the companyId can change within the same application. It’s a constant within the same application, or it can have a different value for the same application? (To know if you can use global filter or not).

Comment: In short....companyId=User.Identity.CompanyId. There are 2 companies with 20 users in each. I need to filter data and show items which belong only to current user's company. Every model extends BaseModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

> So, companyId won't change while a user logged in.

You cannot use a Global Filter for a predicate that's not global to all queries.

If you use a global filter, all queries will be compiled using by example the company A. However, if someone from the company B log into your application, all filtered query will still use compiled query from the company A.

Unfortunately, for your scenario, our EF+ Query Filter cannot be used.

I recommend you to try instead [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters), they maybe handle better this kind of scenario and our library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the DynamicFilters and it was a nightmare to setup working environment with selenium tests, the code was refusing to work half of the time.. Plus, EF+ is just performing better :) I might just remove dozens of virtual properties and update data repositories to use eager loading.  Fyi, in my current setup, the filter in the description miraculously works with one-to-one relationship (EF6,it only fails to load virtual collections.